# Drawing Line in Two Views At a Time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am doing an app in which i need to draw lines in one view and that automatically should appear in the other view. Any help would be appreciated..

I have tried this..

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
slv = [[SmoothLineView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(DrawingView.bounds.origin.x, DrawingView.bounds.origin.y + 42, DrawingView.bounds.size.width, DrawingView.bounds.size.height - 42)];
slv.delegate = self;
[DrawingView addSubview:slv];
}


-(IBAction)btnAnotherView:(UIButton *)sender
{
[zoomingTypingView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
if(sender.tag == 123)
{
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.500 alpha:1.000]];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:0.1
                        options:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp
                     animations:^{
                         //animation code
                         zoomingTypingView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 549, 768, 451);

                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {


                     }];       
    CGRect imageFrame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 220, 120);
    ResizableView = [[SPUserResizableView alloc] initWithFrame:imageFrame];
    CGRect gripFrame = CGRectMake(50,50, 220,120);
    UIView *zoom = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:gripFrame];
    UIScrollView *zoomscroll = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:gripFrame];
    [zoomscroll setZoomScale:32.0];
    [zoomscroll setMaximumZoomScale:32.0];
    [zoom addSubview:zoomscroll];
    [ResizableView setContentView:zoom];
    ResizableView.delegate = self;
    [DrawingView addSubview:ResizableView];
    sender.tag = 246;
}
else
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:0.1
                        options:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp
                     animations:^{
                         //animation code
                         zoomingTypingView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 999, 768, 451);

                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                        [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
                     }];
    [ResizableView removeFromSuperview];
    [DrawingView addSubview:slv1];
    sender.tag = 123;
}
```

}

[image]

In the above Image WhiteColored View is the new View and if i draw in that whiteColoredView that should reflect in both the views.

**You can get more idea by looking at the NOTE TAKER HD APP.**

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FdGDnUKZcMM

Answer (score 0):

If you have two views defined:

```
@property(nonatomic) UIView *view1;
@property(nonatomic) UIView *view2;
```

instead of do self.view, you can have function does the drawing for one view:

```
-(void)drawView:(UIView*)view{
  //your drawing code here
}
```

And just call the same function twice with passing different views.

Comment: how do you update the view, I recommend you use the default drawRect method for each view